# remove \n from paragraph

Tags: php, newline

I have a jquery editable div that when you click on it you can edit the text. The problem is that when the data is called from the db and placed into the paragraph I keep getting a `\n` for every space. How can I replace the `\n` with an actual new line.

I tried `nl2br()`, but that's not very convenient for my users since they then have to play with the `<br />` when they want to edit the paragraph.

Any thoughts?

Comment: the div loads with the textarea to edit the text, or you are using html editor.

Comment: I'm using <p> to load the textarea. The user just clicks on the text and the textarea pops up. Everything is working, data gets saved into db and whatnot. I just can't convert the \n to new lines without using <br />'s

Comment: can you just provide some code, means when user clicks how the data loads to the textarea.I thing their is some problem in quotes. because if string that has \n character called into textarea the \n automatically treated as line break in textarea.

Comment: I think the core issue is not how to get rid of these anomolies, but rather what is putting them there in the first place. If you manually go into the database and look at the data are the \n occurances  there? Are they being added before db insertion or only when retrieving it? Once we know that we will need to see the relevant area of code to find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

try:-

```
$strippedText = str_replace(chr(10), '', $textFromDB);
```

or

```
$strippedText = str_replace(chr(10), '<br/>', $textFromDB);
```

Does this work? (Working on the possiblity that the newlines are already escaped).

```
$strippedText = str_replace('\\n', ' ', $textFromDB);
```

Comment: maybe the `\n` is already escaped, which is why it displays. Can you post some of the problem output in your question please?

Comment: All I want is for the \n to make a new line instead of displaying as \n

I can't replace \n with <br /> because it will confuse my users when they edit the paragraph. The text is inline-editable. When the text is clicked the \n parses automatically in the textarea, but not in the <p> html tag. Don't know why.

When I check my db the data is formatted how I want it, but for some reason I can't output it without the \n

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I would like to see some of the formatted output so I can try and help.

Comment: Here's the textarea. Works perfectly http://screensnapr.com/v/XMDOhF.png

Here's after I click safe:
http://screensnapr.com/v/8zxwjq.png

Comment: Edited. Try strip_slashes() as above

Comment: did you mean stripslashes() ?

If so, it removed all the slashes and left the text with just `n` instead of `\n`

Comment: I meant strip_slashes didn't work, but stripslases did. The result was that it removed the slash from "\n" so I was left with just "n".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5182/discussion-between-vascowhite-and-user962449)

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
str_replace("\\n", "", $str); // see if this gets rid of them
```

Then this should work to put actual newlines in there:

```
str_replace("\\n", "\n", $str); // should replace with actual newline
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a ready made solution or making your own? I use http://aloha-editor.org/ for stuff like this and it's mostly problem free.

Comment: I do not require something complicated. I just use a simple textarea :)

Comment: I can respect that, as I like to keep my code relatively lean. But numerous issues with newlines doing this sort of thing taught me that sometimes a good plugin ends up being the simpler solution if you consider the time it takes to make it work right. Just my opinion though.

Comment: @SyntaxError he's using [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried str_replace?

```
$myTextFromDB = str_replace('\n', PHP_EOL, $myTextFromDB);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think this is different enough that I should do a separate answer for it.

Are you saying a literal "slash n" shows up on the page? Or are you saying that your newlines show up as spaces?

If it's the latter, then there's no way around that. HTML will show newlines only as a space - you have to convert to br tags to break the line if it's not in a textarea context. But you can always convert them back to newlines when you pop that textarea up for your user and this should work well for people.